# How to create reduction functions in rainbow tables?

Tags: hash, cryptanalysis, collision-resistance, rainbow-table

I have been trying to understand rainbow tables lately and one part is giving me trouble to understand here. Let's say I want to generate a table where the chains are 100 000 hash/plaintext long. I have 50 000 hash to reduce then.

1. Is it necessary to have 50 000 different reducing functions to avoid the collisions?
2. How do I create those reduction functions (not just take the n-first letters of the hash for instance) ?

Comment: I don't think so, I already know how reduction function work I just don't know how to generate a lot of them, different from each other.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that does not really answer this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1. Is it necessary to have 50 000 different reducing functions to avoid the collisions?

Yes. If you do not have different functions it is not a rainbow table. It is just a table of hash chains which is less efficient, especially for high coverage tables. However, the functions do not have to be unrelated, just different.

> 2. How do I create those reduction functions (not just take the n-first letters of the hash for instance) ?

Any way you want, as long as it leads to an even distribution and different functions. The simplest is to:

1. Use the size of the search set (of passwords, keys or what have you) and take the hash value modulo that, so the last bits/bytes if the set size is a power of two.
2. Then, to create different reduction functions you can add the index of the function to the value. I.e. you add nothing for the first, 1 for the second function and so on. This is sufficient, since the next hashing step will cause these small changes to again give a completely different output.
3. Finally you turn the value into an element of the search set. E.g. encode it into lowercase letters if that is what you are looking for.

---

The simplest example is if you are looking for a binary key. For example, you are building a rainbow table for DES, which has 56-bit keys (ignoring parity) and 64-bit output.

You can use the last 56 bits of the output (i.e. the whole output modulo $2^{56}$) and add $i$ (again modulo $2^{56}$) for the $i$th reduction function. Pseudocode:

```
def R(i, x): # i'th reduction function
    return (x + i) % (2**56)
```

---

In the case of passwords, suppose you build a table for eight-letter lowercase passwords hashed with MD5. There are $26^8$ such passwords, so you can take the hash value, interpreted as a 128-bit integer and compute `(x + i) % (26**8)` instead.

(Or you could take the latter half of the hash as a 64-bit integer, then do the same.)

Comment: Thanks for answer ! Could you give me an example of your three steps ? I didn't understand the "take the hash value modulo that" part.

Comment: @Shashimee, added.

Comment: I don't see the point of the modulo 2**56 :/ Could you do a concrete example please ? Let's say I have 8 characters-long passwords and 15 characters-long hashes. Example : hash=a5re8ze1sj2o5n1. What would be the first and second reduction function for instance (with a random hash function) ? Sorry but I always learn by concrete examples.

Comment: @Shashimee, that *was* a concrete example, but I added another based on passwords. I didn't use your hash value since I did not know the encoding.

Comment: Okay, I get it now ! Thanks for taking the time to answer